# Plotting the difference between two datetime64[ns]

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

Hi I have a dataframe which contains 2 columns of type `datetime64[ns]`. I clean the data to remove null (NaT) values (removing rows where null occurs in both columns) and the subtract one column from another to get the difference.

Whats the best way to plot a histogram of this data with minute bins and 10-min bins?

I have tried `numpy.histrogram` (which returned error: `TypeError: ufunc add cannot use operands with types dtype('<m8[ns]') and dtype('float64')`) and `hist(series)` (which returned error: `KeyError: 0`).

When I do `series.dtype` return is `<m8[ns]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's generate some data:

```
import numpy as np
d1 = np.arange(np.datetime64('2014-11-01 12:00'), np.datetime64('2014-11-01 14:00'))
d2 = d1.copy()
np.random.shuffle(d2)
diff = d2 - d1
```

The type of the difference is now - as you found out - a timedelta. Here, it's minutes:

```
>>> diff.dtype
dtype('<m8[m]')
```

But we need floats or integers, so cast our data:

```
>>> plt.hist(diff.astype(np.int32))
(array([  3.,   9.,  11.,  17.,  17.,  27.,  10.,  12.,  11.,   3.]), array([-115. ,  -92.2,  -69.4,  -46.6,  -23.8,   -1. ,   21.8,   44.6,
         67.4,   90.2,  113. ]), <a list of 10 Patch objects>)
>>> plt.ylabel('time difference [m]')
```

[image]

The trick in detail: We've converted the timedeltas to integers (could also have been floats, but we don't need them here).

```
>>> diff.astype(np.int32)
array([  78,   47,   55,   25,   22,   58,  113,    0,   -3,    7,   95,
        104,   10,   69,   16,   34,   87,   -2,   83,   16,   77,   48,
         10,   30,   52,   31,   47,   54,   83,  -21,   16,   76,   85,
         58,   68,   12,   74,    1,   68,   21,  -15,  -27,   -6,    1,
         -3,   43,  -34,   32,   46,  -22,    5,  -48,   16,  -33,   55,
        -37,  -25,  -53,  -21,  -48,   54,  -51,  -33,   20,  -12,   48,
         14,  -34,    6,   -2,  -36,    6,   20,  -67,  -55,   43,   32,
        -12,   11,   16,    5,  -31,   34,   21,  -20,   11,  -77,  -26,
        -18,    1,  -18,  -68,    6,   19,  -92,   -9,   -9,  -26,  -40,
        -98,  -34,   -1,  -43,  -82,  -65,  -88,  -52,  -32,  -84,  -58,
        -97,  -49,  -13,  -73,  -71, -115,  -71,  -24,  -76,  -35], dtype=int32)
```

Or if you need them in seconds, convert them first to seconds and then to integers:

```
>>> diff.astype('m8[s]').astype(np.int32)
array([ 4680,  2820,  3300,  1500,  1320,  3480,  6780,     0,  -180,
         420,  5700,  6240,   600,  4140,   960,  2040,  5220,  -120,
        4980,   960,  4620,  2880,   600,  1800,  3120,  1860,  2820,
        3240,  4980, -1260,   960,  4560,  5100,  3480,  4080,   720,
        4440,    60,  4080,  1260,  -900, -1620,  -360,    60,  -180,
        2580, -2040,  1920,  2760, -1320,   300, -2880,   960, -1980,
        3300, -2220, -1500, -3180, -1260, -2880,  3240, -3060, -1980,
        1200,  -720,  2880,   840, -2040,   360,  -120, -2160,   360,
        1200, -4020, -3300,  2580,  1920,  -720,   660,   960,   300,
       -1860,  2040,  1260, -1200,   660, -4620, -1560, -1080,    60,
       -1080, -4080,   360,  1140, -5520,  -540,  -540, -1560, -2400,
       -5880, -2040,   -60, -2580, -4920, -3900, -5280, -3120, -1920,
       -5040, -3480, -5820, -2940,  -780, -4380, -4260, -6900, -4260,
       -1440, -4560, -2100], dtype=int32)
```

It may be necessary to cast to float instead of integer, depending on the precision of the data:

```
diff.astype('m8[s]').astype(np.float32)
```

Comment: Thanks for this explanation - most of it works except when I try to do 'plt.hist(diff.astype(np.int32))' I get an error saying 'cannot astype a timedelta from [timedelta64[ns]] to [int32]' - any ideas?

Comment: Maybe your timedelta's are floats, then it can't cast directly to integer, use `np.float32` for example. Will include that in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This might be way overdue, but it could help someone. I wanted to achieve the same thing and did a cast, but had an error. Realized my timedelta was in [ns]. So i had to cast to [s] first, then it could be casted to float.

```
time_delta.astype('m8[s]').astype(np.float32)
```

Comment: This worked for me, but in the end I ended up skipping the cast/astype entirely by using time_delta.dt.days.hist()